# Why wont GEE upload my image to drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-drive

Im trying to export to my drive a cropped image of NDVI from the dataset 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI', in the layer it shows perfectly but when i submit the task to upload it to drive it never finishes, after 10 hours i cancel the task because it shouldnt take that long. I have tried many times but it wont work and im running out of time please help.

Code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');
var colorized = dataset.select('NDVI');
print(colorized)
var ndvi=colorized.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
print(ndvi)

var ndvi_crop=ndvi.clip(geometry);

var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(ndvi_crop, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_crop,
  description: 'avg_NDVI_2017',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
});
```

Thats what i want to export:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkqui.png

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `region` parameter. Also, if your geometry isn't too large, you might not need the `maxPixels` parameter.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_crop,
  description: 'avg_NDVI_2017',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry 
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!